# X-ray: Observation of absorption edge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, experimental-physics, experimental-technique, x-rays

So I am working on this experiment on X-ray and kinda stuck on this last and following section.

[image]

I have done the measurements and plotted the graph as required in 1. and 2. See below,

[image]

However, I am afraid my graph doesn't look much similar to the graph from Kaye and Laby[3,p. 4.2.2 graph], the one below.

[image]

I would be very grateful if someone can please help me with and explanation to point 3. of the task and also the following 2 questions, **Question 2** and **Question 3**. Thanks in advance.

Link to Kaye and Laby [3,p. 4.2.1 table]: http://www.kayelaby.npl.co.uk/atomic_and_nuclear_physics/4_2/4_2_1.html

Comment: You need to state your ideas about the answers to these questions. Doing that might help you answer the questions by yourself.

Comment: I fixed the photon energy to 5.899 keV which is also the k_alpha energy in the table from Kaye and Laby [3,p. 4.2.1 table]. When compared  the values of k_alpha of Mn source with that of the absorbers, I figured that only Fe absorber has a higher value and others have less value than the source Mn. 

My idea is that, for Question 2, because There is a general tendency for µ/ρ to drop with increasing quantum energy. If energy is sufficiently large, all the orbital electrons of the absorber can be ejected in the atomic photoelectric effect.

Comment: As energy is reduced, one eventually reaches the point where energy is less than the binding energy of a shell, or sub-shell of orbital electrons, and because these electrons are no longer available for ejecting, the absorption ’suddenly’ drops - i.e. we have an absorption edge. But, my confusion is, in the table of data the k_alpha energy for chromium is less than the photon energy which is fixed at 5.899 keV. Then why is there a sudden drop at that region in my curve? Or am I missing something obvious here? Please help me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The $\rm K_\alpha$ X-ray emission is due to an $\rm L$-shell electron falling into the $\rm K$-shell with the emission of a photon.
The $\rm K_\beta$ X-ray emission is due to an M-shell electron falling into the $\rm K$-shell with the emission of a photon with a higher energy than that of a $\rm K_\alpha$ photon.

As the atomic number increases so does the energy of the $\rm K$-photons.

In the reverse process an incoming photon, if it has enough energy, can knock out an electron which is in the $\rm K$-shell.
You will note that the energy of an incoming photon has to be greater than $\rm K_\alpha$, $\rm K_\beta$ etc photons because the incoming photon has to remove the electron in the $\rm K$-shell from the atom completely not just promote the electron into a higher energy level.
So for a given element, the energy of the $\rm K$-edge is greater than the $\rm K$-photons.

Comment: How does it relate to Question 3 though? $\rm K_\beta$ energy for nickel is 8.265 keV and for copper $\rm K_\beta$ and $\rm K_\alpha$ energies are 8.048 keV and 8.905 keV respectively. Is it because $\rm K_\beta$ energy of nickel is more than the $\rm K_\beta$ energy of copper that the $\rm K_\beta$ x-rays are reduced and $\rm K_\alpha$ x-rays are unaffected?